# FFmpeg overlay image behind object

Tags: ffmpeg, video, overlay

I have a video, that has a scene I need to overlay a photo.
The scene looks like this.

[image: original]

I've done simple overlay in the middle of the picture with

```
ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -loop 1 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=t=in:st=0:d=1.5:alpha=1, loop=loop=-1:size=120[fg];
[0:v][fg] overlay=520:230:enable='between(t,15,19)':shortest=1" -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

and the result is kinda fine

[image: my result]

But maybe there's a way to put image behind the frames? So that it overlays only in the places, where pixels are black

Comment: At minimum, you need to either be able to invoke a colour-key, or use a png with transparency, like - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMdd6.png - [rough as heck, no care taken ;) which would give you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkMMZ.jpg I don't know how to do this in ffmpeg, only in such as Photoshop, so i can't help in the code, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

colorkey

```
ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "
[0]scale=640:-2,pad=720:404:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[b];
[1]format=rgb24,colorkey=black:0.05:0[f];
[b][f]overlay
" output.mp4 -y
```

Comment: it works for 2 still images but i have a video and an image. can you help to modify the command, so it works with video?

Comment: fixed and added pad. change sizes for yours